# Zurb Foundation Framework: Fixed Icon Bar as Nav Bar

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have been able to position the icon bar how I want it, with the exception that it displaces the entirety of the page. What is there a class or something I could use to prevent this? Also, I have a footer as you might see, but it is not black as it is from the foundation website that I took the code from (yes I plan on editing this code, I am just in the learning phase right now).

My Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

      <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
          <ul class="title-area">
              <li class="name">
                  <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
              </li>
              <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
              <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
          </ul>

          <section class="top-bar-section">
              <!-- Right Nav Section -->
              <ul class="right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
                  <li class="has-dropdown">
                      <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>

              <!-- Left Nav Section -->
              <ul class="left">
                  <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
              </ul>
          </section>
      </nav>



    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h1>Welcome to Foundation</h1>
      </div>
    </div>


      <ul class="off-canvas-list">
          <ul class="side-nav">
              <div class="icon-bar vertical five-up" role="navigation">
                  <a class="item">
                      <img src="../assets/img/images/fi-home.svg" >
                      <label>Home</label>
                  </a>
                  <a class="item">
                      <img src="../assets/img/images/fi-bookmark.svg" >
                      <label>Bookmark</label>
                  </a>
                  <a class="item">
                      <img src="../assets/img/images/fi-info.svg" >
                      <label>Info</label>
                  </a>
                  <a class="item">
                      <img src="../assets/img/images/fi-mail.svg" >
                      <label>Mail</label>
                  </a>
                  <a class="item">
                      <img src="../assets/img/images/fi-like.svg" >
                      <label>Like</label>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </ul>
      </ul>



      <div class="zurb-footer-bottom">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="medium-4 medium-4 push-8 columns">
                  <ul class="home-social">
                      <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/ZURB" class="twitter"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/ZURB" class="facebook"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/contact" class="mail"></a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="medium-8 medium-8 pull-4 columns">
                  <a href="http://www.zurb.com" class="zurb-logo regular"></a>
                  <ul class="zurb-links">
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/about">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/blog">Blog</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/news">News<span class="show-for-medium-up"> &amp; Events</span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/sitemap">Sitemap</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <p class="copyright">© 1998–2014 ZURB, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how you want it"? What does "displaces the entire page" mean? It's unclear what exactly you want to achieve, so how can we help you? I tried to reproduce your problem in jsfiddle, is this how it looks for you as well? http://jsfiddle.net/zqr7wen7/

Comment: I would like to have a fixed sidebar that does not interfere with the rest of the pages content. Some of my previous attempts made it so that the icon bar forced the body of the page to be below it, so that there was only whitespace to the right of the icon bar. The sidebar that I want is kind of like this one http://stugreenham.com/demos/fluid-width-with-a-fixed-sidebar/, but would not cover the entire vertical section and would stay about mid height no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.zurb-links li{
    display:inline;
}

.sideBar{
    height:100%;
    position:fixed !important; /* added !important just for the snippet to work. not needed for live production..
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/5.4.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
          <ul class="title-area">
              <li class="name">
                  <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
              </li>
              <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
              <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
          </ul>

          <section class="top-bar-section">
              <!-- Right Nav Section -->
              <ul class="right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
                  <li class="has-dropdown">
                      <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>

              <!-- Left Nav Section -->
              <ul class="left">
                  <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
              </ul>
          </section>
      </nav>



    <div class="row ">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h1>Welcome to Foundation</h1>
      </div>
    </div>


      <div class="row ">
          <div class="small-4 medium-2 columns sideBar">
          <ul class="side-nav">
              <div class="icon-bar vertical five-up" role="navigation">                  <a class="item">
                      <img src="../assets/img/images/fi-home.svg" >
                      <label>Home</label>
                  </a>
                  <a class="item">
                      <img src="../assets/img/images/fi-bookmark.svg" >
                      <label>Bookmark</label>
                  </a>
                  <a class="item">
                      <img src="../assets/img/images/fi-info.svg" >
                      <label>Info</label>
                  </a>
                  <a class="item">
                      <img src="../assets/img/images/fi-mail.svg" >
                      <label>Mail</label>
                  </a>
                  <a class="item">
                      <img src="../assets/img/images/fi-like.svg" >
                      <label>Like</label>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </ul>
                      </div>
          <div class="small-8 medium-10 small-push-4 medium-push-2 columns">        
              <p>I have been able to position the icon bar how I want it, with the exception that it displaces the entirety of the page. What is there a class or something I could use to prevent this? Also, I have a footer as you might see, but it is not black as it is from the foundation website that I took the code from (yes I plan on editing this code, I am just in the learning phase right now).I have been able to position the icon bar how I want it, with the exception that it displaces the entirety of the page. What is there a class or something I could use to prevent this? Also, I have a footer as you might see, but it is not black as it is from the foundation website that I took the code from (yes I plan on editing this code, I am just in the learning phase right now).I have been able to position the icon bar how I want it, with the exception that it displaces the entirety of the page. What is there a class or something I could use to prevent this? Also, I have a footer as you might see, but it is not black as it is from the foundation website that I took the code from (yes I plan on editing this code, I am just in the learning phase right now).I have been able to position the icon bar how I want it, with the exception that it displaces the entirety of the page. What is there a class or something I could use to prevent this? Also, I have a footer as you might see, but it is not black as it is from the foundation website that I took the code from (yes I plan on editing this code, I am just in the learning phase right now).I have been able to position the icon bar how I want it, with the exception that it displaces the entirety of the page. What is there a class or something I could use to prevent this? Also, I have a footer as you might see, but it is not black as it is from the foundation website that I took the code from (yes I plan on editing this code, I am just in the learning phase right now).I have been able to position the icon bar how I want it, with the exception that it displaces the entirety of the page. What is there a class or something I could use to prevent this? Also, I have a footer as you might see, but it is not black as it is from the foundation website that I took the code from (yes I plan on editing this code, I am just in the learning phase right now).</p>
              
      <div class="zurb-footer-bottom">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="medium-4 medium-4 push-8 columns">
                  <ul class="home-social">
                      <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/ZURB" class="twitter"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/ZURB" class="facebook"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/contact" class="mail"></a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="medium-8 medium-8 pull-4 columns">
                  <a href="http://www.zurb.com" class="zurb-logo regular"></a>
                  <ul class="zurb-links">
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/about">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/blog">Blog</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/news">News<span class="show-for-medium-up"> &amp; Events</span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://zurb.com/sitemap">Sitemap</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <p class="copyright">© 1998–2014 ZURB, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
           </div>                      
    




    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.4.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqr7wen7/3/)

.
If you want to fix your side bar in your web page you have to go with `position:fixed`.
The problem that one faces by doing this is that rest of the columns are relatively positioned -they go under the side-bar or on top of it(including the footer if you span to 100% width).

In the fiddle i gave a span of `small-4 and medium-2 columns` for side-bar , `small-8 and medium-10 small-push-4 medium-2-push columns` for content and nested footer in to this.

As the side-bar has `position:fixed` the content column(`position:relative`) stacks underneath it so i push the columns based on the span of side-bar.

```
 <div class="row ">
     <div class="small-4 medium-2 columns sideBar">
         <ul class="side-nav">
            ....             
            ..
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="small-8 medium-10 small-push-4 medium-push-2 columns">   
          <p>Your content</p>
            .....
            ...
          <div class="zurb-footer-bottom">
            ....
            ..
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i added important just for snippet..u dont need to have it..if you have custom css after foundation css

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Here is my solution:

HTML-Code:

```
<body>

<!-- Header content "top-bar" ... -->

    <div class="icon-bar vertical side_fixed hide-for-small-only">
      <a class="item">
        <label>Menuitem 1</label>
      </a>
      <a class="item">
        <label>Menuitem 2</label>
      </a>
      <a class="item">
        <label>Menuitem 3</label>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="admin_content">

    <!-- Main-Content   "row" "column" ... -->
    <!-- footer -->

    </div>
<!-- scripts -->
</body>
```

SCSS-Code: (CSS similar)

```
@media #{$medium-up} {
  .side_fixed {
    left: 0;
    top: $topbar-height;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 8rem;
    max-width: 8rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .admin_content {
    margin-left: 9rem;
  }
}
```